Sobolev Embedding Theorem: counter example cone condition
Let be $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an open subset that satisfies the cone condition.
According to Sobolev's theorem, the following continuous embedding holds for $k>\frac{n}{p}$
$$W^{k,p}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C_b(\Omega)$$
where $C_b(\Omega)$ contains all continuous and bounded functions on $\Omega$. 
Now I wonder if the cone condition is necessary for this embedding. For this, I have constructed a set that does not satisfy the cone condition:
$$\Omega:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^a<y<2x^a, 0<x<1\}$$ for $a>0$ sufficently small.
My question is: Can I find a function $ f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $p>2$ for which there is no continuous function in its equivalence class? Any help is greatly appreciated!

For $a$ small enough depending on $p$, we can find a $b>0$ such that $1+1/a>p(b+1)$, consider $f(x,y)=y^{-b}$ we have $\nabla f=(0,-by^{-b-1})$, which means
$$\int_\Omega|\nabla f|^p\approx_{a,p}\int_0^1y^{-p(b+1)}y^{1/a}dy<\infty.$$
$f$ cannot belongs to $C_b(\Omega)$ because no matter what equivalent class you choose we always have $\limsup_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\infty$, since the essential infimum of $f$ on $\{(x,y)\in\Omega:y<\epsilon\}$ is exactly $\epsilon^{-b}$.

Thank you for your helpful answer! But I do not understand why $\limsup_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\infty$ implies that $u$ has no continuous representative

@Oscar210899 I guess you mean "bounded representative". $f$ itself is continuous in the domain.

Actually, I want to know if there exists a function that has no continuous representative. Or is this guaranteed by Sobolev embedding theorem?

Take a reflection copy of $\Omega$ on the left hand side and f vanishing on that copy. Then f, along with all its representative, is discontinuous at the origin. There is no hope to be discontinuous at the interior as it follows from the classical Sobolev embedding on balls.
